# Pandas DataFrame: Unusual Behaviour with json.dumps ( Extra double quotes )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Pandas DataFrame with two columns `label` and `time`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':{'tier':'one','app':'frontend'},'time':100}])
>>> df
                                        a  time
0  {u'tier': u'one', u'app': u'frontend'}   100
```

Column `label` stores a dict.

When I print the dataframe, I get the expected row values

```
>>> print(df.to_csv(index=False,header=False,sep='|'))
{'tier': 'one', 'app': 'frontend'}|100
```

I wanted to convert these row JSON values to a string and hence I did

```
>>> df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
>>> df
                                    a  time
0  {"tier": "one", "app": "frontend"}   100
```

But with df.to_csv(), I get this issue where I get two times double quotes

```
>>> print(df.to_csv(index=False,header=False,sep='|'))
"{""tier"": ""one"", ""app"": ""frontend""}"|100
```

When the expected output should be

```
{"tier": "one", "app": "frontend"}|100
```

This behaviour seems very unusual. Am I going wrong somewhere here ?

Comment: Try `doublequote=False` in `to_csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE** in **to_csv** function, as:

```
import csv
print(df.to_csv(index=False,header=False,sep='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE))
```

For more details, read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).